# Google Action Builder Account Linking

Tags: actions-on-google, account-linking, actions-builder

I'm using the brand new Google Action Builder and I'm having a problem with Account Linking ( OAuth & Google Sign In & Implicit flow ):
After account linking is performed, Google should attach the `access_token` to conv parameters but I don't find it in any webhook request. I'm sure that account linking is performed well because in settings I see the unlink button and in every request I see `"accountLinkingStatus": "LINKED"` and `"verificationStatus": "VERIFIED"`.
Also I tested the flow on oauthplayground and I receive an access_token at the end of the flow. Where could the problem is hidden ?

Comment: Hi Claudioc am struck  in one point please tell me this is possible or not, am using only `OAuth` linking I need to authenticate user in my database and then allow account inking in `Node js` is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

The client library will extracts credentials from an authorization header, saving the values in user.params.

If a client ID is passed, validates and decode the authHeader as a GSI token.

`conv.user.params.tokenPayload`

If not, extract the token value from the header (if the header contains a bearer token).

`conv.user.params.bearerToken`